# ORACLE SQL Count or having count

Tags: sql, count

Trying to retrieve number of artists with more than 1 copy, I'm trying using following SQL it returning an error.

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function 00937. 00000 - "not a
>   single-group group function" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 22
>   Column: 8

```
SELECT W.WORKID,A.LASTNAME,A.FISRTNAME, COUNT(W.ARTISTID) AS Orders
FROM ( WORK W INNER JOIN ARTIST A
ON W.ARTISTID=A.ARTISTID)
GROUP BY A.LASTNAME, W.WORKID, A.FISRTNAME
HAVING COUNT (W.ARTISTID) > 1;

SELECT WORKID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME
FROM WORK W, ARTIST A
WHERE W.ARTISTID = A.ARTISTID
HAVING COUNT (W.ARTISTID) > 1;
```

Comment: what is the error you get? should `fisrtname` be `firstname`?

Comment: please add your error output.

Comment: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 22 Column: 8

Comment: YEAH i CORRECTED firstname..

Comment: ARTIST id IS A unique id. in the work table there are number of works done by artists. artist may have done one or more works.

I'm trying to get the artist name who has done more than 1 work .

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.LASTNAME,A.FIRSTNAME, COUNT(W.ARTISTID) AS Orders
FROM (WORK W INNER JOIN ARTIST A
ON W.ARTISTID=A.ARTISTID)
GROUP BY A.LASTNAME, A.FIRSTNAME
HAVING COUNT (W.ARTISTID) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not mentioning constraints in below example--

```
CREATE TABLE WORK1 ( ARTISTID NUMBER(10),WORKID NUMBER(10));

create table ARTIST  ( ARTISTID number(10),lastname varchar2(10),firstname varchar2 (10));

INSERT INTO ARTIST VALUES (1,'a','aa');
insert into ARTIST values (2,'b','bb');
insert into ARTIST values (3,'c','cc');
commit;


INSERT INTO WORK1 VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO WORK1 VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO WORK1 VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO WORK1 VALUES (2,4);
INSERT INTO WORK1 VALUES (3,5);
commit;
```

And then, a `Left outer join` will help you to get desired output-

```
SELECT COUNT(C.artist) as Orders,
  C.LASTNAME,
  C.FIRSTNAME
FROM
  (SELECT A.ARTISTID AS artist ,
    B.WORKID         AS workid,
    A.LASTNAME       AS lastname,
    A.FIRSTNAME      AS firstname
  FROM ARTIST A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WORK1 B
  ON A.ARTISTID=B.ARTISTID
  )C
GROUP BY C.LASTNAME,
  C.FIRSTNAME
HAVING COUNT(C.artist)>1;
```

Output--

```
ORDERS LASTNAME   FIRSTNAME
------ ---------- ----------
     2 b          bb         
     2 a          aa
```